# Notice: Undefined index: files in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php on line 1

Tags: magento-1.9, core, code, app

Notice: Undefined index: files  in `/home//public_html/.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php` on line 139

```
#0 /home//public_html/.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php(139): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Undefined index...', '/home/farmacam/...', 139, Array)
#1 /home//public_html/.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App/Area.php(146): Mage_Core_Model_Translate->init('adminhtml')
#2 /home//public_html/.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App/Area.php(121): Mage_Core_Model_App_Area->_initTranslate()
#3 /home//public_html/.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App/Area.php(93): Mage_Core_Model_App_Area->_loadPart('translate')
#4 /home//public_html/.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(774): Mage_Core_Model_App_Area->load()
#5 /home//public_html/.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(512): Mage_Core_Model_App->loadArea('adminhtml')
#6 /home//public_html/.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#7 /home//public_html/.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#8 /home//public_html/.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#9 /home//public_html/.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 /home//public_html/.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 /home//public_html/.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /home//public_html/.com/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}
```

TRANSLATE.PHP:

```
foreach ($this->getModulesConfig() as $moduleName=>$info) {
            Mage::log($moduleName);
            $info = $info->asArray();
            $this->_loadModuleTranslation($moduleName, $info["files"], $forceReload);

        }
```

var_dump($info["files"]):

```
array(1) { ["default"]=> string(13) "Mage_Core.csv" }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an error in the word "files" in a config.xml file of some module.
It would be better to use Xdebug for this, however you can also debug like this:

```
foreach ($this->getModulesConfig() as $moduleName=>$info) {
        $info = $info->asArray();

        if (!isset($info['files'])) {
            Mage::log($moduleName);
        }

        $this->_loadModuleTranslation($moduleName, $info['files'], $forceReload);
    }
```

You will have in your log the module that is in trouble. Look in the config.xml of the part of translate:

```
<translate>
        <modules>
            <vendor_module>
                <files> <!-- Probably this word is not correct! (files) -->
                    <default>Vendor_Module.csv</default>
                </files>
            </vendor_module>
        </modules>
    </translate>
```

Comment: Thanks Rafael! This worked as expected. In my case, the faulty module was `Rapidcommerce/Ias`: in its `config.xml`, the module name was nested inside `<files>`, istead of the other way around.